# Illegal Initialization In C Program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I tried to run this code in the Turbo C and got illegal initialization at line 9
What did I do wrong???

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{

 int names[] = {23,23,34};

 int *nam[] = { names, names+1 , names +2};

 char *temp;

 clrscr();


 printf("%u" , (nam));

 getch();
}
```

Comment: use C99 compiler later.

Comment: TurboC is *ancient*, avoid it if you can. And you can, because there are many free C compilers out there, that are up to date with modern standards. There are also many free complete environments that are better than the old TurboC as well.

Comment: As for your problem, it's probably a quirk in TurboC because that initialization is valid. There are other things that are not valid in your program though, like printing out the ***pointer*** to the first element in `nam` using the wrong format.

Comment: Get a new compiler, there's plenty of excellent, modern ones available for free. For beginners, I would recommend the default installation of Codeblocks with gcc pre-installed and pre-configured.

Comment: What operating system (OS) does your computer use?

Answer (score 3):

You get this problem because your compiler is hopelessly outdated. In an old C standard, which was withdrawn 17 years ago, you couldn't initialize arrays with anything but compile-time constants.

In 1999 there was a new C standard which fixed a lot of flaws like this. In order to compile this code, you need a compiler which supports the "C99" update of the language.